# Find a Jordan form of a non-diagonazable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am trying to find Jordan's form of this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
-4&  4& 0\\ 
-2 &  1& 2
\end{pmatrix}
The only eigenvalue $r$ is 2 and therefore the simplest eigenvector $v_{1}$ is (0, 0, 1)
To get the other two independent vectors (generalized eigenvectors) for the P matrix we need to compute $(A-rI)v_{2}=v_{1}$ and $(A-rI)v_{3}=v_{2}$ .

However, in the calculation for 2 I get the following system which has no solution:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -2 & 0&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  1&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 & 1 
\end{array}
\right] $$

Any Idea on what I am doing wrong? If the eigenvalue is 2, when we substract it the lowest row will always contain all zeros...

Comment: You assume that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$ is $1$ and that $(0,0,1)$ spans the eigenspace. This assumption is wrong. The geometric multiplicity of $2$ is $2.$ Try to find another eigenvector which is independent of the first one and continue from there.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier That deserves to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: If all you need is the Jordan normal form and not the full decomposition, there’s no need to compute generalized eigenvectors. The multiplicities of the lone eigenvalue tell you what the Jordan matrix must be.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thanks! I actually had a very simple calculation error, that's why I wasn't able to find different vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this method for hand calculations: first, calling your matrix $A,$ let
$$ B = A - 2 I  $$
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-2&1&0 \\
-4&2&0 \\
-2&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
A basis for the genuine eigenvectors is given by the convenient
$$
E =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0 \\
2&0 \\
0&1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
We may or may not be using these eigenvectors in the form shown. We know that the characteristic equation for $A$ is just showing $B^3 = 0.$ However, the minimal polynomial for $A$ is $B^2 = 0,$ which you can check easily enough.

We are going to make a matrix $R$ with columns $u,v,w;$ on the far right, we take $w$ as any vector with $B^2 w = 0$ (automatic) but $Bw \neq 0.$ Then $v = Bw$ will be a genuine eigenvector. Finally, we will choose an independent eigenvalue $u.$

I like ones and zeros, I choose
 $$
w =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Then from $v = B w$ we get
 $$
v =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This $v$ is a genuine eigenvector, it is the sum of the two columns of my $E.$
At last, we get to choose some $u$ eigenvector that is not a multiple of $v,$ I choose 
 $$
u =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
1&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Next we find $R^{-1} $ and $J = R^{-1}A R,$ which will be the Jordan form if we did it correctly. A piece of luck , because of choosing ones and zeros, the determinant of $R$ is small, actually $1,$ and we calculate

$$
R^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&1 \\
1&0&0 \\
-2&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and

$$
J = R^{-1} A R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&0&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
0&0&2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$  $$
$$ R^{-1} A R = J  $$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&1 \\
1&0&0 \\
-2&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
-4&4&0 \\
-2&1&2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
1&1&0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&0&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
0&0&2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$  $$
$$ R J R^{-1} = A  $$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
1&1&0
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&0&0 \\
0&2&1 \\
0&0&2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&1 \\
1&0&0 \\
-2&1&0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
-4&4&0 \\
-2&1&2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**COMMENT:** the line above  "as any vector with $B^2 w = 0$ (automatic)" may appear silly. If, however, you were given a 5 by 5 matrix $A$ with characteristic polynomial $(x - 5)^3 (x-7)^2$ and minimal polynomial 
$(x - 5)^2 (x-7),$ the demand for a vector $w$ with $(A - 5I)^2 w = 0$ but $(A - 5I) w \neq 0$ would make some sense, as the eigenvalue $7$ is ignored in this condition.